# Searching through a string trying to find &#39; in PHP

Tags: php

I am using tinyMCE and, rather annoyingly, it replaces all of my apostrophes with their HTML numeric equivalent. Now most of the time this isn't a problem but for some reason I am having a problem storing the apostrophe replacement. So i have to search through the string and replace them all. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

did you try:

```
$string = str_replace("&#39;", "<replacement>", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it just apostrophes that you want decoded from HTML entities, or everything?

```
print html_entity_decode("Hello, that&#39;s an apostophe.", ENT_QUOTE);
```

will print

```
Hello, that's an apostrophe.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why work around the problem when you can fix the cause? You can just turn of the TinyMCE entity encoding*. More info: [here](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/entity_encoding)

*Unless you want all the other characters encoded, that is.

Comment: Cheers! Unfortunately i need to leave it on so flash can read all the other characters properly.